# How to manipulate Collections.TQueue order?

Tags: delphi, queue, delphi-xe2

I have a queue in which I store packets to be transmitted:

```
TfrmFoo = class(TForm)
    public
        tx_queue: System.Generics.Collections.TObjectQueue<TPacket>;
```

Sometimes I need to queue a packet with the top-most priority. This is how I would do it:

```
for i := 0 to tx_queue.Count do
    // Shift all queue items one space up the queue.
    tx_queue.FItems[tx_queue.Count - i + 1] :=
        tx_queue.FItems[tx_queue.Count - i];
// Add a packet to the--now vacant--top-most position.
tx_queue.FItems[0] := VipPacket;
```

Unfortunately, `FItems` is private so I don't have access to it:

```
E2361 Cannot access private symbol {System.Generics.Collections}TQueue<Comm.TPacket>.FItems
```

How can I do what I described without rolling my own FIFO queue data structure, as I still want to be able to use all the features offered by the stdlib?

**UPDATE**: Having 2 queues is a solution, but there is another place in my code where I require access to the Queue items, e.g. where I print the queue:

```
DebugMsg('Contents of Tx-Queue:');
for i := 0 to (tx_queue.Count - 1) do
    DebugMsg(tx_queue.FItems[i]);
```

or a function that iterates over the queue and counts how many packets of a certain ID have been queued.

Comment: Why not just enqueue packets with higher priority into a secondary queue ?

Comment: Don't you just use two queues? One for high priority, one for standard.

Comment: @TLama Thank you guys for the solution but I still have the requirement to access individual queue items (see update). Is this possible?

Comment: I just had the idea to `Dequeue()` everything into some temporary container, do whatever I need to do with the `TPacket`s and then re-`Enqueue()` everything back. But to do this just to **read** some queued item seems ugly and inefficient.

Comment: Queues aren't meant to be random access.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, exactly! It looks like `TQueue` is not the proper class for the task.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why is that? Is it not useful to see what's coming up soon in the queue or to manipulate the order of the queue?

Comment: Use an array (list in Delphi terminology) for random access

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm actually refactoring the queue away from a static array because I thought it was ugly and really inconvenient and error-prone and opted to use a data-structure from stdlib. TLama suggested `TQueue.ToArray()` which is perfect to read the queue (he deleted it; maybe he's writing an answer).

Comment: I didn't say "static array". What Delphi terms list is in standard Cs terms an array. Something with O(1) random access. Creating a copy with ToArray seems inefficient. If you want access to the entire container's content, don't use a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A queue isn't meant to be manipulated the way you want to manipulate your data structure. Use [`TList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) instead. Use `Add` to put things on the back, `Insert` to put something on the front, and `ExtractItem(0)` to fetch the first item.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. To clarify, to put something on the front of the queue, I would need to `TList.Move()` everything one space up the list before `Insert()`ing the `VipPacket`?

Comment: Delete the item the insert it position zero

Comment: Oh right. I thought that `MyList.Insert(0, VipPacket)` would overwrite what's in `MyList[0]`, but now I see that it wedges the new packet in without destroying anything. Thanks

Comment: This whole Q&A makes me wonder really what can `TQueue` do that `TList` can't do just as easily? `TList` pretty much has all the methods and properties of `TQueue`, but it can do so much more.

Comment: @NewWorld What `TList` cannot do is enque and deque without either moving up or moving down and incurring a significant memory copy overhead. That can be an immense performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to assign different priorities to different items, then one common approach is to implement two queues. One for high priority items, one for the rest. Exhaust the high priority items before considering the other items.

It is possible to enumerate the items of `TQueue<T>`. And consequently you can do so for the derived class `TObjectQueue<T>`. The `TQueue<T>` class provides an enumerator so you can write your code like this:

```
DebugMsg('Contents of Tx-Queue:');
for item in tx_queue do
  DebugMsg(item);
```

Comment: Did you notice that is indeed possible to enumerate the items in a queue?